# Is there a way to detect if app was installed with Market or not?

Tags: android

I am wondering if I am able to detect if my application was installed with Android Market (it's in the download list of the Market and eligible for update checks) or it's not?

It would be a very good point to detect if the app has been installed without, as that can mean it was stolen and installed from SDcard.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In your activity do

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
String installationSource = pm.getInstallerPackageName(getPackageName());
```

installationSource will now hold the package name of the app that installed your app.

testing with an app of mine installation source is "com.google.android.feedback" when installed via google market, null if installed via debugger.

Comment: Does anyone know what the corresponding package name is for the Amazon market?

Comment: Recently Android Market had package "com.android.vending"

Comment: Package name for Amazon Market is com.amazon.venezia

Comment: Having checked the Samsung store website, it appears that this would also be null for apps installed via that method.

Comment: [Link to the Samsung Developers Forum discussion about the matter](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/getinstallerpackagename-return-value-in-samsung-phones/77/177735).

Comment: List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("com.android.vending", "com.google.android.feedback"));
if (installationSource != null && list.contains(installationSource)) return true;

Answer (score 0):

If you're not root (and have access to Market database), I don't think it's possible.

Comment: they should provide a contenrprovider with the db