# Tracking installs from users outside of google play?

Tags: android, google-play

I am pretty new to app analytics and I seem to have encountered something quite strange.

I am getting "Ghost" installs showing up in my analytics. This is clearly stemming from a user that installed the app outside of the play store via an APK. Therefore google play did not register the install. However, when they are in the app and take an action or engage with the app in some way I can then track that this user is using the app. But i cannot see where he installed it from.

I want to be able to find all users like this... who have installed this app outside of the play store. Is this possible at all?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes. it possible. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178043/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-app-was-installed-with-market-or-not

Comment: Thanks for the link. I still feel this doesn't fully answer it though.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Facebook SDK to track installs. It is more accurate than Google Play's tracking.

My implementation uses Facebook App Events for Android.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/android