# How can we know whether an app is installed through playstore or other market?

Tags: android

I have developed an android app.I want everyone to download it from playstore.I want to know whether there is any method to check whether my android app is installed from playstore or other market?
I think by checking that i can make my app more secure.

Comment: [Is there a way to detect if app was installed with Market or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5833459/4235666) I think that may be the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well i am not sure but after analyzing the packages i have installed using google play i say you  can use package manager commander form shell and there will be native implementation for that.
So my analysis is that the packages with **installer=com.android.vending** are installed from google play store

> pm list packages -i
>
> shell@Colors_X47:/ $ pm list packages -i
>   package:com.google.android.ears  **installer=null**
>   package:com.android.defcontainer  **installer=null**
>   package:com.android.quicksearchbox  **installer=null**
>   package:com.android.smsregister  **installer=null**
>   package:com.android.contacts  **installer=null**
>   package:com.mediatek.voiceunlock  **installer=null**
>   package:com.mediatek.lbs.em  installer=null package:com.android.phone 
>   installer=null package:com.android.calculator2  installer=null
>   package:net.cactii.flash2  installer=null
>   package:com.android.htmlviewer  installer=null
>   package:com.google.android.gsf.login  installer=null
>   package:com.azmathunzai.lebcms  installer=null
>   package:jackpal.androidterm  **installer=com.android.vending**
>   package:com.android.wallpaperchooser  installer=null
>   package:com.google.android.tts  **installer=com.android.vending**
>   package:com.android.providers.telephony  installer=null
>   package:com.mediatek.schpwronoff  installer=null
>   package:com.mediatek.CellConnService  installer=null

New Finding:
[You can use  String getInstallerPackageName (String packageName) Follow link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

Use `PackageManager` to do this:

```
public void licenseChecker() {
    String mSource = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
            .getInstallerPackageName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
    if (mSource != null && mSource.startsWith("com.android.vending")) {
        // YOUR LOGIC HERE
        Log.d("*** Success Checker", "Play Store");
    } else {
        // YOUR LOGIC HERE
        Log.d("*** Failure Checker", "Other Market");
    }
```