# Would package installerID of an app change if an app is shared via apk sharing, like ShareIt?

Tags: android

I am trying to recognise from app if the app was not installed from play store and some other source. I first read this answer [Detect if an app is installed from Play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539949/detect-if-an-app-is-installed-from-play-store/37540163#37540163)
But then, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16862957 said amazon:

> **finally sets** PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName() to
>   "com.amazon.venezia"

So is it optional to change the package installer name?

If yes, then if the app is shared via apk then is the package name installer changed?

For example if the app was shared via shareit, would the package name installer change?

I just want to be sure that if I use the method in the first answer, I can also identify installs by such sharing.

If it won't change when shared via apk, is there a way to find out whether it was shared via apk?

Answer (score 0):

The package name will be whatever it is set by the developer.

Some third party stores will add their own tag like "freeapk.com.company.appname", but as far as submission and downloading from Google play or Amazon, the only way to know which store it came from would be to see if the developer created two different versions of the app.