# unique signature/key in android app installed from play store

Tags: android

Retrieve some kind of unique key/signature that can be read in android app if only installed only from play store.

The closest I got to was "https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation" which seems exactly what I want but I'm still trying to wrap my head around it. It seems that you can create tokens but I don't want the token to change each time I get it !!

I want to use this key to decrypt a string but don't want the key to be in the app.

Comment: There is no service that does that.  Google Play doesn't store or send down decryption keys for your app.  I suggest you describe what you're trying to protect and what threat vectors you're trying to protect against so you can get advice on what the right thing to do is.

Comment: Thanks Gabe. I basically want a way to decrypt a string in the app but I don't the key to be inside the app. 

There is a way to check if the app is installed from play store so I was wondering if there is some unique identifier I can get .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539949/detect-if-an-app-is-installed-from-play-store 

The above only helps protect if APK is pirated but doesn't prevent say asset extraction or class extraction from dex file to get source code ..

Comment: Also, I tried using the instance ID, it does return a string but that unique only for the app lifetime. On reinstall there is a new ID so doesn't look like that is the mechanism for me ..

Comment: If the user needs to log into your app, you can send it from the server. Otherwise there's no way to do this that isn't easily defeated

Comment: Instance is is a token for Google play services. It's not suitable as an encrypting key