# Play Store: Detect at runtime if this is a production version

Tags: java, android, google-play

Is there a way to detect, whether an app has been installed through the "Internal test", "Alpha", "Beta" or "Production" channel of the play store?

Setting a marker or a build config field in the apk at compile time is not the solution, as an apk can be propagated from a channel to another (like Beta->Production)

So some kind of runtime detection would be needed.
Also of interest is the information whether it was installed through play store at all (and not from another source).

Any guidance/hints where to start with this would be great!
Thank you.

Comment: whether or not it comes from play store: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539949/detect-if-an-app-is-installed-from-play-store - the other part: I don't know.

Comment: why do you need to detect this?

Comment: Two reasons: First, because we want to show in the app, that it is from the "alpha program" if the install is not from the release channel. A build variable/build field does not help here because we would lose the ability to propagate an alpha/beta version to production without a new build number/apk version number and second: the alpha version allows connections to different backends than the production. I know how to do that all with gradle. But the question is, whether it's possible without a recompile.