# How to remove Temporary ad serving limit placed on your adMob account

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I have a simple app on play store and all i have to 4 users .. no one installed it and i got this email from adMob . My question is if i edit my app and removed ads from it and update it on store may that affect my account on adMob and other solution ,if i unpublish the app would that make my adMob account be disabled .. please help me

Comment: same issue since 18/06 :/

Comment: We could use a check if the ad is shown from admob and on failure request to another ad network like mopub. This strategy can be integrated until ad limit is removed.

Answer (score 18):

For the People experiencing Ad Serving has been Limited,The only Solution is
(by my personal experience)

1. Delete All Ad Unit Id's of All your Apps
2. Wait for 7-15 days (May take even Longer) and the warning disappears

Unfortunately this is the only way (thanks to google's shitty bots),for some people the warning went away after 2-3 weeks but for me it didn't even go away after a month before i deleted all Ad Unit Id's

But now the warning might be gone but there is always a risk of it coming back in future,for this i recommend to use Mediation (Highly recommend Mopub).

Never ever depend on a single advertising partner (especially admob).
You can find more info on how to work with mediation here -
[Importance of Mediation and why everyone should use it](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ebsptt/important_of_mediation_and_why_everyone_should/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share)

Edit - Ad serving limit appears again after you do a successful live ad request, this might be because our apps are sideloaded to apk sites and google thinks its invalid traffic
Try this solution for  [Android users Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539949/detect-if-an-app-is-installed-from-play-store)

Comment: Your solution works, but unfortunately when you add a new ad unit, the warring will appear again

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI can you try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539949/detect-if-an-app-is-installed-from-play-store

Comment: Thank you, but I see that too many apps published on Huawei App Gallery and the other store as well as the 3rd-party stores and the ads served fine in those apps

Comment: We could use a check if the ad is shown from admob and on failure request to another ad network like mopub. This strategy can be integrated until ad limit is removed. please let me know if this will violate admob policy.

Comment: I received this warning more than three times
The solution is simply to avoid placing the ads incorrectly (start screen - before loading the page - when the user is focusing on something - do not surprise users with the ads - do not repeat the same ad more than once for one user - etc.)

Comment: Hi @AnishJain, did this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539949/detect-if-an-app-is-installed-from-play-store) which you mentioned in the edit, worked for you to remove ad serving limit?

Comment: one more best solution for this is if the user click on one ad then stop showing ads to for short time period to that user there is way to this

Comment: @midou I agree to the point of not placing the ad at start screen and  not suprising the user with ads, but how do you make sure that you dont repeat the same ad more than once per user. What ads are shown to the user is not under your control right? It depends on the user browse history. This is seriously frustrating from google

Comment: Is it enough just to delete units from the admob dashboard, or do we need also to prevent requests from the app?

Comment: I think you might be right I was doing exactly that @midou

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the account was blocked due to improper usage...
What happens with the app, shouldn't have any effect over the AdMob account..

Comment: That means that my adMob account may be disabled at anytime

Comment: I got the same email 3 days ago. My account is been running for 6 months I recommend you to check how your ads are placed once, for me it happened when there was a large spike of adrequest and match rate couldn't keep up other than that I don't know how long it will take I really hope this gets fixed soon

Comment: The problem is .. if my acount is blocked does that mean that i can't use it again anymore or just for period of time

Comment: @AnishJain  have you got any solution => same problem happen with me as number of user increasing in my app which increase the adrequest  and i get this msg in my account [Temporary ad serving limit placed on your AdMob account]

Comment: @miteshviradiya check out my answer it will help