# How to check if the app is downloaded from Google Play Store or Samsung Galaxy Store?

Tags: google-play, samsung-galaxy

Currently I am uploading my app to Google Play Store. So I have linked some buttons to Google Play Store for more apps and rating. Now I am trying to upload the app to Galaxy Store. However, for them, Play Store links needs either to be removed from the app or update them with Galaxy Store links. I found a way to check if the app is downloaded from the Play Store using the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539949/detect-if-an-app-is-installed-from-play-store). How to check if it is downloaded from Galaxy Store?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val pm = packageManager
val installer = pm.getInstallerPackageName(packageName)
```

The package name for the Samsung Galaxy Apps Store is `com.sec.android.app.samsungapps.`