# How I can protect my own paid apk from sharing?

Tags: javascript, android, security, smali

How I can protect my apk which I sell outside of playstor from leaking and publicly sharing ?, like locking it by device id, IMEI or something like this, i want it to work only in one device

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is used for questions/issues regarding the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37539949/13419694)?

Answer (score 0):

Make your app must login to use. Server shouldnt respond to any invalid payments etc. Fully safe.

## 95+% Safe Method:

```
Server must not return anything like any sort of data.
Means app is useless without server.
And server is not accessible without login
```