# How to check how many users are downloading and/or using a hacked version of an app?

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console

I am trying to find a way to understand how many users are downloading and/or using unofficial hacked versions of our app but I could not find anything about it.

First of all, are these included in Play Console download figures or not? Is there a way to understand how many downloads hacked apk's get? We have implemented our system for events tracking but I guess it can be disabled in an hacked apk, so looking at the number of people using it without being subscribed would possibly provide biased estimates. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539949/detect-if-an-app-is-installed-from-play-store

Comment: Fow should a user install a modified version from Google Play? Of course hacked versions  are not included Play Console download figures. Modified versions are always side-loaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know an application is installed from google play or side-load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809438/how-to-know-an-application-is-installed-from-google-play-or-side-load)