# Restrict my App to only download from Googe Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, apk

How do I make sure people install my Android Application from **Google Play Store** and not from **APK** distributed over internet as **`.APK` packages**?

Comment: you should set license https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing

Comment: Why `down vote`? I believe it's concise, specific and to the point, the only problem this question has _What have I done so far?_ Well, I research a lot with same keywords but got nothing. Believe me I just go to know there is something called `Licensing ` in Android SDK just because of this question. So the person who `-1` should explain why he thought it to be out of standards? Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Exclude your app from certain devices
The excluded devices list is based on your most recently uploaded APK. If you upload a new APK with a different manifest file, the list will change.

Note: Device exclusion rules don't apply to internal testers.

*emphasized text*

**Manage excluded devices per app**

To prevent app crashes, you can exclude your app from being available to individual devices on Google Play. Making this change manually excludes your whole app—you can't exclude individual APKs.

By manually excluding devices with known compatibility issues, you can help provide a better experience for your users.

**Exclude a device**

1. Sign in to your [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/).
2. Select an app.
3. On the left menu, select Release management > Device catalog.
4. Select a device.
5. At the bottom of your screen, select Exclude.

**Use the same excluded devices as another app**

1. Sign in to your [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/).
2. Select an app.
3. On the left menu, select Release management > Device catalog.
4. Select the Excluded devices tab.
5. Next to "Import manually excluded devices," select an app.
6. Select Import.

**Set up exclusions for a device with multiple models**

1. Sign in to your [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/).
2. Select an app.
3. On the left menu, select Release management > Device catalog.
   -If your app hasn’t been published yet, select Device catalog.
4. Select a device. Devices with multiple models are labeled.
5. To exclude all models of the device, go to the top right corner of the screen and select Exclude all **models**.
   -*Other models are listed under the first model’s details. To view details for other models, go to the right side of the screen and select the down arrow.*
   -To exclude one model of the device, go the bottom right corner of a model’s details and select **Exclude**.

*Note: To exclude your app from all devices made by one manufacturer, you need to exclude devices one at a time.*

*Check this for more details*

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by checking getInstallerPackageName.

But there are some reasons you wouldn't want to use this.
Read them here: [Is it ok to check legality of installing paid android app by checking getInstallerPackageName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083349/is-it-ok-to-check-legality-of-installing-paid-android-app-by-checking-getinstall/36299631#36299631)

Also, you could use `In-app Billing`: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

Or `Licensing`: https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html