# What is the package name of the Google Play app and the AndroidPIT app?

Tags: android, installation, package

What is the package name of the Google Play app and the AndroidPIT app?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's **com.android.vending** - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4439898/570168

and **de.androidpit.app** - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.androidpit.app

Answer (score 13):

Google Play's package name is `com.android.vending`

Comment: @maveň It actually is `com.android.vending`. It's just not available for download in the playstore.

Answer (score 2):

if you have the .apk files wit you can download **re-sign.jar** file and you can find the **package name** and **main activity class name**

Comment: Can you post a link to download re-sign.jar?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumForAPKFiles u can downlaod from this link(click on from here)