# What are exactly Google Play package names?

Tags: android, package, google-play

What are exactly Google Play package names in the past (let prefix them with old) and nowadays?

I know this:

```
private static final String GooglePlayStorePackageNameOld = "com.android.market";
private static final String GooglePlayStorePackageNameNew = "com.android.vending";
private static final String GoogleAndroidPitPackageName  = "de.androidpit.app";
```

Not sure about `"com.android.market"`, should it be `com.android` or `com.google`?

Answer (score 1):

It's **com.android.vending** and try for this link and go for use code:

[What is the package name of the Android Market or Google Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439043/what-is-the-package-name-of-the-android-market-or-google-apps/4439898#4439898)