# Possible to determine installation method of Android app?

Tags: android, installation, google-play, amazon-appstore

Is it possible to determine the installation method of your Android application?  Google Play, Amazon, manual install, bundled, etc and if so how?  This is a similar quesiton to [Detect if app was downloaded from Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986627/detect-if-app-was-downloaded-from-android-market) but in this case the signatures would be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bake a value into the APK released to each store, indicating which store (or other distribution method) it is for.  This same value could be used to configure all the changes required for that store.

Comment: Right, duh!  I was thinking that would mess up the certificate signing but obviously not.

Comment: I cannot speak to whether the certificate signing might differ on Amazon vs. Google Play, as so far I have only released apps on Google Play, and so do not know what signing process is used by Amazon.  I am only commenting regarding the way to determine whether you're dealing with an Amazon or a Google Play version.

I am assuming that there are enough differences between Amazon and Google Play (e.g., DRM used by Amazon) that it will not be practical to release the same exact APK on both stores, and so if that is correct, then baking a value into each APK provides the simplest solution.